# Skaffold: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon on Docker Desktop for macOS

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, docker-desktop, skaffold

I get the following message when I run the `skaffold dev` command:

> Build Failed. Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:
> ///var/run/docker.sock. Check if docker is running.

Tools versions:

1. MacOS Desktop Docker: 4.13.0 (89412)
2. Kubernetes: v1.25.2
3. Skaffold: v2.0.0

Docker runs correctly in fact I can create resources on the cluster and create containers with the docker-cli commands. I successfully launch both docker info and docker version.

The command `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/com.docker.diagnose check`

reports

> "No fatal errors detected."

(all tests pass).

I also tried setting the `DOCKER_HOST` variable:
`DOCKER_HOST = /Users/<my folder>/.docker/run/docker.sock skaffold dev`

Result:

```
invalid skaffold config: error getting docker client: unable to parse docker host `/Users/<my folder>/.docker/run/docker.sock`
```

My Skaffold.yaml file

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v3
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: test
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: <myimage>
      context: <folder>
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
manifests:
  rawYaml:
    - infra/k8s/deployment.yaml
```

How can I solve?

Answer (score 6):

The solution was to set the variable DOCKER_HOST before launching the `skaffold dev` command:

```
DOCKER_HOST="unix:///Users/<you>/.docker/run/docker.sock" skaffold dev
```

Answer (score 2):

The Docker Api use the docker.sock to communicate with the docker engine, that allow you to run commands like ***docker run myimage***

Usually the docker.sock is located at **/var/run/docker.sock** when you use docker-ce or docker.io.
I see that you are using a **desktop version** of docker, so the paths are not the same anymore. and thats why skaffold can't find the docker daemon.

I am on Ubuntu so i found it at `/home/<you>/.docker/desktop/docker.sock`

When you got the path you have to create a link :

```
sudo ln -sf /home/<you>/.docker/desktop/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock
```

Use your default docker context :

```
docker context use default
```

and check that you indeed changed the context with :

```
docker context ls
```

now check if your docker client can find the docker daemon :

```
docker ps -a
```

if you have no errors good to run your *skaffold dev*

you can also specify to skaffold to use the docker CLI:

```
build:
  local:
    push: false
    useDockerCLI: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, followed a load of solutions but nothing working, i'm on an M1 mac pro.

Goto https://docs.docker.com/desktop/uninstall/ and follow the uninstall instructions.

Then reinstall docker desktop & it should start working again.